# Null value error - inserting data into SQl database

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Database and read/write data to it. Some context - Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10, Connecting to SQL Server 2005 over VPN, Using ADO.Net 4.1. My code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Class MainWindow

Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand


Private Sub btn_WriteInt_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_WriteInt.Click

    Try
        'Establish connection to SQL Database
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=serverIP;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        'Save data to table
        Dim int_IntTest As Integer = Int(txt_IntTest.Text)
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_SQLTest([IntTest]) VALUES('" & txt_IntTest.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btn_TestInt_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_TestInt.Click
    Dim int_IntTest As Integer = Int(txt_IntTest.Text)
    MsgBox(int_IntTest)
End Sub
End Class
```

The SQL Server table looks like this: [tbl_SQLTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2j04.png)

When I run the application, enter "2" into txt_IntTest and click btn_WriteInt, I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]]

Comment: You aren't inserting any value for that column.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: In your DBMS set a default value for that column. Then when nothing is passed your default would be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a new row in the table if you don't add a value for 'StringTest' column null is added, so you need to do one of these:

- Allow null for this column un your table,
- Pass an empty value in your query.
- Add a default `''` in the `StringTest` column.

Comment: ah i see, I didnt add and name a new row. Would you mind giving me the syntax for adding and naming the row in my cmd.CommandText statement?

Comment: Yes, "INSERT INTO tbl_SQLTest (IntTest, StringTest) VALUES ('yourdata', ' ')";

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer (which I think is the correct one and I upvoted). I recommend you to do something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_SQLTest([IntTest], [StringTest) VALUES(@intTest, @stringTest)"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intTest", Int(txt_IntTest.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stringTest", "")

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Use `Add` and specify the data type... consequences could occur; for example precision...